# How to design simulation of a user interface for UX/UI evaluation?

Tags: gui-design, user-research, interface, usability-testing

I want to design to a simulation of a User Interface for usability testing, e.g. the User Interface of the Car showing speed, rpm, and other indications. I may want to stop the simulation after a set duration during the experiments. 
What would be the fastest way to do? Should I use the javascript? Or there is another software or programming langue to make the simulation or prototypes quickly? GitHub?
Please give some advice and recommendation? I will be thankful to you.
[image]

Comment: @postpolice We're talking about how to create prototypes for user testing. Designers and developers don't know how to do this. Farm points elsewhere.

Comment: I recommend ForeUI

Answer (score 3):

The best way to create prototypes is Adobe Animate. With Animate, you can take one animation, interface design, interaction animation, or whatever and create real native iOS and Android apps, .exe .swf or HTML5 for desktop, and pixel perfect video or animated gif.

And again, it does all that from ONE source file. Once you create your dashboard in Animate, you can export everywhere. You just have to deal with display dimensions.

Animate is like Photoshop. It's very deep but does simple stuff easily too and will help you. You can drop jpegs or vector in Animate from Photoshop or Illustrator or create vector in  Animate. Everything is on a timeline.

If there's no interaction, only animation in your prototype, use video. Make the animation work in Animate on your desktop and just use screencapture to make videos out of it.